# How to Join two tables showing all records Where Table A is Not In Table B

Tags: sql

I have a email marketing web application. I want to show which email contacts in (Table B) are not showing up in EmailContacts_Campaign (Table A).  In addition, I want to filter table A by the CampaignId field.  When I run the below code I get 0 records, yet I know there are a couple of thousand records there. Can anyone tell me where I am messing up?

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.EmailContactId = TableB.EmailContactId
WHERE TableA.CampaignId = 1 
AND TableB.EmailContactId IS NULL
ORDER BY TableB.EmailContactId DESC
```

I want to show all email contacts in the `EmailContact` Table that are not showing up in the `EmailContactCampaign` table. Here is the actual code:

```
public List<EmailContact> GetNotAssignedContactsForCampaign(int campaignId)
        {
            string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM EmailContactCampaign LEFT JOIN EmailContact";
            sqlCommand += " ON EmailContactCampaign.EmailContact_EmailContactId = EmailContact.EmailContactId";
            sqlCommand += " WHERE EmailContactCampaign.EmailContact_EmailContactId = " + campaignId.ToString() AND EmailContact.EmailContactId IS NULL ;
            sqlCommand += " ORDER BY EmailContact.EmailContactId DESC";
            var emailContacts = new List<EmailContact>();

            string CS = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
                //Create sql datareader
                using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        var emailContact = new EmailContact();
                        emailContact.Assigned = ((bool)sqlDataReader["Assigned"]);
                        emailContact.Cell1 = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["Cell1"] as string);
                        emailContact.Cell2 = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["Cell2"] as string);
                        emailContact.City = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["City"] as string);
                        emailContact.Company = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["Company"] as string);
                        emailContact.EmailAddress = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["EmailAddress"] as string);
                        emailContact.EmailContactId = (int)sqlDataReader["EmailContactId"];
                        emailContact.FullName = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["FullName"] as string);
                        emailContact.Hold = (bool)sqlDataReader["Hold"];
                        emailContact.Phone1 = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["Phone1"] as string);
                        emailContact.Phone2 = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["Phone2"] as string);
                        emailContact.State = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["State"] as string);
                        emailContact.Status = (Status)sqlDataReader["Status"];
                        emailContact.Zip = _crypto.DecryptAndSanitize(sqlDataReader["Zip"] as string);
                        emailContacts.Add(emailContact);
                    }

                }
                return (emailContacts);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you really have the quotations around `SELECT * FROM TableA` or is that a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE EmailContactId NOT IN (SELECT EmailContactId FROM tableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you got 0 probably because of this `AND TableB.EmailContactId IS NULL`

Please try this one

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.EmailContactId = TableB.EmailContactId
WHERE TableA.CampaignId = 1
ORDER BY TableB.EmailContactId DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry my question was not clear enough.  Did some digging and found the answer on another post. Sorry but I accidentally closed it and can't find it again. Anyway, here is my implementation of it.

```
SELECT * FROM EmailContact
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM EmailContactCampaign WHERE EmailContactCampaign.EmailContact_EmailContactId = EmailContact.EmailContactId AND EmailContactCampaign.Campaign_CampaignId = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you are looking for B's that are not in A. But your query will return A's that are not in B. Turn it aroung (`tableB left join tableA where a... is NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you had it the wrong way around: your query would return all contacts from `EmailContactCampaign` that were not in `EmailContact`.

The correct solution for your problem would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EmailContact
WHERE EmailContactId NOT IN (
  SELECT EmailContact_EmailContactId FROM EmailContactCampaign
  WHERE Campaign_CampaignId = ?
)
ORDER BY EmailContact.EmailContactId DESC
```